# drawWithFrame NSOutlineView Flickr

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a custom cell class for NSOutlineView
In the cell class I have implemented the drawWithFrame.
The rect provided(cellFrame) I divide into 3 parts
(a) Image
(b) Text
(c) Darwing  (ellipse/circle / rectangle)

The image is drawn using    [image compositeToPoint:imageFrame.origin operation:NSCompositeSourceOver];
The ellipse is drawn using [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:ellipseRect xRadius:10 yRadius:10] fill];

The text rect is given to the super class to draw the text
    [super drawInteriorWithFrame:newFrame inView:controlView];

Now my problem is that when any cell of the outline view expands, all the drawing (ellipse etc) flickr and appear to be redrawn, even if the cell was not expanded.

Can anyone help me to resolve this..

Here is the code

```
- (void)drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView*)controlView
{
    //cellFrame.size.height -=16;
    Option *ol = [self representedObject];

    uint64_t sz;
    int fontSize=10;
    NSString *sizeText;
    MyFile *tmpf;
    //NSImage *image = [ol getImage];

    if (image != nil)
    {
        // the cell has an image: draw the normal item cell
        NSSize imageSize;
        NSRect imageFrame;

        imageSize = [image size];
        NSDivideRect(cellFrame, &imageFrame, &cellFrame, 3 + imageSize.width, NSMinXEdge);

        imageFrame.origin.x += kImageOriginXOffset;
        imageFrame.origin.y -= kImageOriginYOffset;
        imageFrame.size = NSMakeSize(12,12);

        if ([controlView isFlipped])
            imageFrame.origin.y += ceil((cellFrame.size.height + imageFrame.size.height) / 2);
        else
            imageFrame.origin.y += ceil((cellFrame.size.height - imageFrame.size.height) / 2);

        [image compositeToPoint:imageFrame.origin operation:NSCompositeSourceOver];

        imageFrame.origin.y+=18;
        imageFrame.size.width = cellFrame.size.width - 18;
        imageFrame.origin.x+=18;

        sz = [ol getsize];
        /////////////////////////////////

        NSRect newFrame = cellFrame;
        newFrame.origin.x += kTextOriginXOffset;
        newFrame.origin.y += kTextOriginYOffset;
        newFrame.size.height -= kTextHeightAdjust;
        newFrame.size.width -= 65;

        if(sz) 
        {
            //newFrame.origin.x += 65;
            NSRect tmpframe = newFrame;
            NSRect ellipseRect = NSMakeRect(tmpframe.origin.x+tmpframe.size.width+1, 
                                            tmpframe.origin.y+ kTextOriginYOffset,
                                            60,16);

            //////// ****ALLOC ********
            tmpf = [[MyFile alloc] init];
            [tmpf setfsize:sz];
            sizeText = [tmpf getFormattedfize];

            //  [NSShadow setShadowWithOffset:NSMakeSize(0, -8 * 1) blurRadius:12 * 1
            //                          color:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0 alpha:0.75]];
            [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.9 alpha:1.0] set];
            [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:ellipseRect xRadius:10 yRadius:10] fill];
            //  [NSShadow clearShadow];
            TextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSColor textColor], 
                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                              [NSFont systemFontOfSize:10], 
                              NSFontAttributeName, nil];    

            [sizeText drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(ellipseRect.origin.x+3, ellipseRect.origin.y+2)   
                   withAttributes:TextAttributes];

            //////// ****RELEASE *******
            [tmpf release];
        }
        [super drawInteriorWithFrame:newFrame inView:controlView];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your drawing code.

Comment: updated the question with the code